# regexp to extract set of words together from string

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem Statement -**

We need to extract a set of sequential occurring words from a string.

Simplest example is as below with expected input and output.

```
set of words => "word1|word2|word3";

Input string => "i m word1 word2 and this is word3 word2 word1+ i am having this word2 word3.";"

Output => word1 word2
          word3 word2 word1
          word2 word3
```

**Note -- Please note that there is no space in "word1+" and "word3."**

Please consider this a simplest input. Complexity can be to any extend. mean there can be multiple set of words ( say 500 word) and we need to find those set of words which are occurring together from an input string.

I am doing this in javascript hence **what i tried is as below.**

```
var pattern = "word1|word2|word3";
var regobj = new RegExp('((('+pattern+')\\s?)+)', "g");
```

**What is the problem in my solution?**

```
For Input string => "i m word1word2 and this is word3word2 word1+ i am having this word2 word3.";"

it will give output as 
word1word2        -- wrong
word3word2 word1  -- wrong 
word2 word3
```

**Why I want this? or Real Time use case..!**

I want to extract word numbers from an complex expression.say

```
"one thousand two+three hundred four+1.3456+log(twenty)"
```

so here I need to extract

```
one thousand two
three hundred four
twenty
```

and need to replace it respective numerical equivalent.

Comment: If you want a solution in javascript - then I strongly suggest you remove the other tags. Different regex flavours have different methods/feature set, so can't generally be applied. Perl/Python for instance, will also have other ways of solving this that wouldn't be applicable if you're purely using js :)

Answer (score 3):

Use word boundary:

```
\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b
```

The complete regex in action in perl:

```
my $str = 'i m word1word2 and this is word3 word2 word1+ i am having this word2 word3.';
my @l = ($str =~ /((?:\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b(?:\s|\.))+)/g);
dump@l;
```

**output:**

```
("word3 word2 ", "word2 word3.")
```

With the last expression:

```
my $str = 'one thousand two+three hundred four+1.3456+log(twenty)';
my @l = ($str =~ /((?:\b(?:one|two|three|four|twenty|hundred|thousand)\b\s*)+)/g);
dump@l;
```

**output:**

```
("one thousand two", "three hundred four", "twenty")
```

Comment: He wants the continuous matching words as a group.

Comment: @M42-- yes. thefourtheye is correct. This is not the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your problem you could use [Lingua::EN::Words2Nums](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Words2Nums)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Lingua::EN::Words2Nums;

my $string = "one thousand two+three hundred four+1.3456+log(twenty)";
my $re = qr(one|thousand|two|three|hundred|four|twenty);
my @groups = split(m/\+/,$string);
for my $group (@groups) {
    my @words = ($group =~ m/\b$re\b/g);
    next unless @words;
    my $number = words2nums("@words");
    print "@words => $number\n";
}
```

Output:

```
one thousand two => 1002
three hundred four => 304
twenty => 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can use **split** and **grep** for it:

```
perl -e '$w="word1|word2|word3"; while(<>){ print join " ", grep { /$w/ } split /\W/, $_ }' 
i m word1 word2 and this is word3 word2 word1+ i am having this word2 word3.
word1 word2 word3 word2 word1 word2 word3
```

In JavaScript the same functions:

```
var input="i m word1 word2 and this is word3 word2 word1+ i am having this word2 word3.";
var r=new RegExp("^(word1|word2|word3)$");
var wr=new RegExp("\\W");
var out = new Array();
var split = input.split(wr);
for( var i=0; i < split.length; i++) {
  if( split[i].match( r ) ){
    out.push(split[i]);
  }
} 
console.log(out);
```

The output:

```
["word1", "word2", "word3", "word2", "word1", "word2", "word3"]
```